# AbstractAction lambda

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, lambda

IntelliJ is suggesting that I change

```
new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // my code here
        }
}
```

to

```
(AbstractAction) (e) -> {
    // my code here
}
```

When I change my code to the suggested code above, I get the message "target type of a lambda conversion must be an interface".

Comment: It's impossible to know what is going on here without some of the surrounding code.

Comment: Its not really a question :)

Comment: May be the IDE should better suggest `(ActionListener) (e) -> { ... }`

Answer (score 7):

You should implement abstract action class, so you can use it functionally.

```
public class FunctionalAction extends AbstractAction {

    ActionListener myaction;

    public FunctionalAction(ActionListener customaction) {
        this.myaction = customaction;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myaction.actionPerformed(e);
    }

    public ActionListener getMyaction() {
        return myaction;
    }

    public void setMyaction(ActionListener myaction) {
        this.myaction = myaction;
    }

}
```

You can use this class as below:

```
getTexfield().getActionMap().put(actionName, new FunctionalAction(ae -> {
        }));
```